# What is the process to add sub domain with Cloudflare and Cyberpanel whose domain name is used as custom domain name for WP multisite?

Tags: dns, subdomain, cloudflare, openlitespeed, cyber-panel

The domain example.Org is custom domain name  that points to WP Multisite enabled example.Com
WP Mu site example.Com is working fine.

/home/example.Com/

This WPMU example.Com is added via CyberPanel

I need to create a subdomain name like this
ok.example.Org that uses different php-CMS (not the WP )

I'm stuck at the process ..

- Cloudflare > DNS > add A record points to server IP / @
- CyberPanel > Create new website > do.example.Org
  (example.Org points to WPMU .Com site)
  http check result shows
- 302
- Connection Closed

Comment: it won't work if you don't create subdomain do.example.org DNS records and point it to your server

Comment: I have mentioned it as my first step .. done it already.

Comment: but if your first step was add @ record, it won't work